What can be said about a Bi-Heyting algebra when the complement operations are useless?
Imagine, for whatever reason, a bounded lattice[1] $(L, 0, 1, ∧, ∨)$ which is a bi-heyting algebra, i.e. there is an operation $→$ such that $x∧y ≤ z$ iff $x ≤ y→z$ (the heyting algebra structure) and an operation $∖$ such that $x∖y≤z$ iff $x≤y∨z$ (the co-heyting algebra structure).
While the heyting algebra structure already tells us that our lattice is distributive, The hope was that a bi-heyting structure tells us even more.
However, here's the catch: Assume that in this case, the associated dualization operations $¬x ≔ x→0$ and $\sim x ≔1∖x$ both take values in ${0,1}$ only, more specifically, $¬x=1$ if and only if $x=0$ (otherwise $¬x=0$), and $\sim x=0$ if and only if x=1 (otherwise $\sim x=1$). This makes the dualizations completely boring, because they only see the lattice as „top, bottom, neither“, so they loose all interesting information.
Since all of the constructions on (bi-)heyting algebras I've seen so far rely on these dualizations, are there other properties of bi-heyting algebras that could still allow me to make statements about my lattice? For instance, does it allow proving existence of infinite (ascending/descending)chains/antichains/gaps/dense intervals/etc?
[1] of cardinality $2^ω$, if that matters

Not exactly what you're after, but let me mention that on the purely algebraic side (i.e. concerning the finite systems of equations that are satisfied in your lattice), having a bi-Heyting structure won't have any further implications beyond distributivity. This is because (i) the lattice reducts of finite bi-Heyting algebras are precisely the finite distributive lattices, and (ii) bi-Heyting algebras are LEF.
